# Error using postgis st_dimension() function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, navicat

I am using navicat function builder to build a new simple function:

```
SELECT st_dimension(geometry)
FROM nature
```

I want to take the result of the POSTGIS st_dimension function using the table nature and the column geometry that contains geometries as multipolygons.

The return type schema is pg_catalog and the return type is int4

This is the SQL preview:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION "public"."NewProc"(IN  "public"."geometry")
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."int4" AS $BODY$SELECT st_dimension(geometry)
  FROM nature$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

When i am trying to save it a get this error:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE2: RETURNs "pg_catalog"."int4" AS $BODY$SELECT...
                         ^

I tried to do the same with the build in function st_dimension() that it has, with parameter nature.geometry but i get the error:

Procedure execution failed
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "natura"
LINE 1: ... "public"."st_dimension(""public"".""geometry"")"(natura.geo...
             ^

What I am doing wrong with the above function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language should be `'sql'`, not [`'plpgsql'`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html). It isn't clear why you have an `IN` parameter that is not used by the function. Furthermore, if `nature.geometry` has a mixture of dimensions, then it my return the result of a random row, since there is no `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: That did the trick (change language to SQL). I know the fact about ORDER BY. I just wanted it to work for now. Nothing special!